# Evaluate the integral $ \lim_{n \to ∞ } \int_{0}^{1} \frac{n \sin(e^x)}{1+n^2x^2}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, limits, definite-integrals

Evaluate $$ \lim_{n \to ∞ } \int_{0}^{1} \frac{n \sin(e^x)}{1+n^2x^2}dx$$

I could just show that is bounded by $$ \lim_{n \to ∞ } \int_{0}^{1} \frac{-n}{1+n^2x^2}dx ≤ \lim_{n \to ∞ } \int_{0}^{1} \frac{n \sin(e^x)}{1+n^2x^2}dx ≤  \lim_{n \to ∞ } \int_{0}^{1} \frac{n}{1+n^2x^2}dx $$

I looked up if I can swipe the $\lim_{n \to ∞}$ inside the integral and make  $∞/∞$ form to apply L'Hôpital's but I found that we can do so if the function inside integral converges uniformly (& uniform convergence is not a part of my syllabus) even I don't know if it is uniformly convergent & even after applying L'Hôpital's it is seems the same tough. I think there is some other approach to this. Kindly help. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the substitution $y=nx$:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^n\frac{\sin\left(e^{\frac{y}{n}}\right)}{1+y^2}dy \longrightarrow \int_0^\infty \frac{\sin(1)}{1+y^2}dy = \frac{\pi}{2}\sin(1)$$

by your favorite convergence theorem, or by an easier application of squeeze theorem after the variable change.

Comment: In this substitution, can we treat this $n$ as a constant, because we are now differentiating it wrt to $x$ ?

Comment: @Gajjze that is how it works in this context yes because in each step of the sequence, the $n$ is frozen and the integral is computed which eliminates the dummy (integration) variable. That is the default, and that's why extra justification is needed in order to take the $n$ to $\infty$ first then do the integral.